# Cant Zoom Desired Level In Google Maps To Fit 2 Directions In Screen

Tags: android, maps, marker

(I would want to put screenshots put my reputation is low to put them...)
Good Day.I Have two directions(markers) on google maps api(android) between which i want camera to be center,and camera being centered there.But problem is that one marker comes to one edge of screen and another marker to another edge of screen!I don't want it to be like that,i want just to zoom specified level so markers will be center in google maps view and won't be place on edges of screen.I tried to put even 0 zoom level in camera update factory of google maps,but nothing happens at all.Here is my code how do i achieve that

```
 } finally {
                    com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds.Builder boundsBuilder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
                    boundsBuilder.include(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(tolat), Double.parseDouble(tolong)));
                    boundsBuilder.include(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(fromlat), Double.parseDouble(fromlong)));
                    final LatLngBounds bounds = boundsBuilder.build();
                    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 0));
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you say you tried to put 0 as the zoom level. You mean this call `CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 0)` right?

The second parameter is the padding not the zoom level. Set it up (example to 10) and you have a padding to the outer edges.

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/CameraUpdateFactory

I hope it helps.

Comment: oh hmmm....perfect answer ill try it right now!Thank you very much.idk why my android studio won't show short information when i navigate mouse on code and so thats why i couldn't guess the second parametr:S

Comment: PERFECTLY HELPED ANSWER ACCEPTED AS ANSWER AND VOTED UP THANK YOU VERY MUCH COMPLETELY FIXED ISSUE AND MADE WHAT I WANTED THANKS!